# How to make pattern brush with konva JS or pure canvas api

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs, konva

hi i want to make pattern brush like picutre under this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd6WP.png)
(reference : https://app.leonardo.ai/canvas)

I'm using konvaJS so it will be perfect for me telling me how to make pattern brush like that image with konva js

but if there hasn't any solution for konvaJS, I would appreciate for telling me how to make it with pure canvas API thank u!

I tried 'fillPatternImage' option that kovna give to us but it is not working..
anyway i made brush function with Konva.Line

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.